# How to add form field value to query parameter to Contact Form 7 on_sent_ok redirect URL?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have tried several methods for this after searching online, including various SO answers.

Current I am trying this:

Form field code:

```
[dynamichidden form-session-id "form_session_id" id:fsid]
```

Code in Additional Settings:

```
on_sent_ok: 'location.replace("http://www.example.com/page-2/?fsid=" + jQuery("input[form-session-id=form_session_id]").val());'
```

After submitting my form I am redirected to:

http://www.example.com/page-2/?fsid=undefined

Can't get that fsid value in there! I admittedly don't know how to use this portion of the code:

`input[form-session-id=form_session_id]`

So that could be the issue...

---

I have also tried using this code in the Additional Settings field, as seen at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/get-values-from-contact-form-7-wp-plugin:

```
function my_redirect() {
        var fsid = document.getElementById('fsid').value;
        var url = 'http://www.example.com/page-2/?fsid=' + fsid;
        window.location = url;
    }
on_sent_ok: 'my_redirect();'
```

In this case no redirect at all happens.

Answer (score 1):

Does your page actually have this hidden field? On my page it wasn't rendered untill i remove `id:fsid` part from the shortcode: `[dynamichidden form-session-id "form_session_id"]`

In on-sent-ok change `input[form-session-id=form_session_id]` to `input[name=form-session-id]`:

```
on_sent_ok: 'location.replace("http://www.example.com/page-2/?fsid=" + jQuery("input[name=form-session-id]").val());'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking all over for a similar solution and this worked!
Using Contact Form 7, I'm selling tickets on PayPal and I have a quantity field the called 'ticketnumber'.

In Additional Settings I have this:

on_sent_ok: 'location.replace("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXXL&quantity=" + jQuery("input[name=ticketnumber]").val());'

Works like a charm!